# How to divide a cube to a certain grid numbers and find the element in each grids in r?

Tags: r

I have a cube with a dimension of 5 * 5 * 5 m^3 and the cube is full of different elements (oxygen, carbon etc.), the dataset with the coordinates looks like this  -

```
element   x     y     z


Oxygen    1     1     1.2
hydrogen  2.2   2     2.3
oxygen    4.3   3     3
carbon    4     2.3   5
oxygen    3.3   3.5   3
```

Now I want to divide the whole cube into grids of 0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5 m^3 and find out how many of this grids contains oxygen inside a certain region of z (like how many grid have oxygen in (from z = 0 to z = 0.5), from z = 0.5 to z = 1) and so on..)

Now I did the following and i want to simplify it if possible. Help will be much appreciated.

```
    divide <- function(z1, z2, y1, y2, x1, x2){
      oxygen_number <- dt %>% filter(dt$element == 'oxygen' & dt$z >= z1 & dt$z < z2 & dt$y >= y1 & dt$y < y2 & dt$x >= x1 & dt$x < x2) %>% count()
      }
    seqx<- seq(0, 5, 0.5)
    seqy<- seq(0, 5, 0.5)
    by_z <- function(k){
      result = c()
      for (l in seqx) {
        for (m in seqy){
          PP1 <- divide(k, k+0.5, l, l+0.5, m, m+0.5)
          print(PP1)
          result <- rbind(result, PP1)
        }
      }
    }

by_z1 <- by_z(0, 0.5)
by_z2 <- by_z(0.5, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` to see which grid an element lies:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
dtt <- data.frame(
    element = sample(c('C', 'H', 'O'), 10000, replace = TRUE),
    x = runif(10000, 0, 5),
    y = runif(10000, 0, 5),
    z = runif(10000, 0, 5))

dtt %>%
    mutate(
        xbin = cut(x, breaks = seq(0, 5, 0.5), include.lowest = TRUE),
        ybin = cut(y, breaks = seq(0, 5, 0.5), include.lowest = TRUE),
        zbin = cut(z, breaks = seq(0, 5, 0.5), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
    group_by(xbin, ybin, zbin, element) %>%
    tally()

# # A tibble: 2,911 x 5
# # Groups:   xbin, ybin, zbin [1,000]
#    xbin    ybin    zbin    element     n
#    <fct>   <fct>   <fct>   <fct>   <int>
#  1 [0,0.5] [0,0.5] [0,0.5] C           3
#  2 [0,0.5] [0,0.5] [0,0.5] H           9
#  3 [0,0.5] [0,0.5] [0,0.5] O           7
#  4 [0,0.5] [0,0.5] (0.5,1] C           5
#  5 [0,0.5] [0,0.5] (0.5,1] H           2
#  6 [0,0.5] [0,0.5] (0.5,1] O           1
#  7 [0,0.5] [0,0.5] (1,1.5] C           5
#  8 [0,0.5] [0,0.5] (1,1.5] H           3
#  9 [0,0.5] [0,0.5] (1,1.5] O           6
# 10 [0,0.5] [0,0.5] (1.5,2] C           4
# # … with 2,901 more rows
```

Comment: findInterval would have returned a numeric value.